# Application stop after some time android eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, download

I made a simple application, which just download some data from internet and then process it continuously. But I found that after a half or some time application stops working when screen is turned off. And there is no error on application. It seems like application restarted and every thing normal,just not downloading data. Here is my code.

```
class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        // constants
        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        int timeoutConnection = 5000;

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        System.out.println(GlobalVariables.getRandomString(15));
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url[0] + "?id=" + GlobalVariables.getRandomString(15));
        try {
            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(httpget);
            getResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control:", "no-cache");
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("MyApp", "Download Error: " + statusCode + "| for URL: " + url);
                return null;
            }

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResponseEntity.getContent()));  

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
                total.append("\n");
            }

            line = total.toString();
            return line;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("MyApp", "Download Exception : " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        TextView txtstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);
        txtstatus.setText("Status: Downloading Data, Please Wait....");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            TextView txtstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);
            txtstatus.setText("Status: Downloading Complete.");
            if(result.toString().length() > 10) {
                errorcount = 0;
                MyMessageDetails Detail;
                String[] mydata = result.split("\\|s\\|");
                for (String value : mydata) 
                {
                    if (value.contains("|")){
                        String[] details = value.split("\\|n\\|");
                        String mymsg = null;
                        Detail = new MyMessageDetails();
                        Detail.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        for (String mydetail : details) 
                        {

                            if (mydetail.startsWith("_From:_")){
                                mymsg = "From: " + mydetail.replace("_From:_", "")+ "\n";
    Detail.setMsgBody(mymsg);
                            }
                        }
                        titles.add(Detail);
                    }

                }
                if (titles.size() > 0){
                    ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstmsgs);
                    ca = new CustomAdapter(titles , MainActivity.this);
                    listView1.setAdapter(ca);
                }else{
                    if (StartInfo){

                                         new RequestTask().execute(BaseUrl);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (StartInfo){

                    new RequestTask().execute(BaseUrl);
                }
            }

        } catch(NullPointerException e) {

                TextView txtstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);
                txtstatus.setText("Status: " + "Error: " + e.getCause());
        }

    }
```

**Update**
LogCat look like this.

```
09-08 22:16:32.650: D/jdwp(9057): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x3F
09-08 22:16:32.713: D/ActivityThread(9057): BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{417d01d0 com.golden.smsserver}}
09-08 22:16:32.788: D/ThemeManager(9057): contextandroid.app.ContextImpl@417d2460
09-08 22:16:32.788: D/ThemeManager(9057): create ThemeManager object
09-08 22:16:32.789: D/ThemeManager(9057): Res_clear()
09-08 22:16:32.806: D/ThemeManager(9057): packageName=====com.golden.smsserver
09-08 22:16:32.809: D/ThemeManager(9057): packageName=com.golden.smsserver
09-08 22:16:32.810: V/Provider/Setting(9057): invalidate [system]: current 25 != cached 0
09-08 22:16:32.813: D/RRR(9057): path=other/bottom/bottom7.png
09-08 22:16:32.872: D/ThemeManager(9057): sIconWidth=64----sIconHeight=64
09-08 22:16:32.875: D/ThemeManagerHH(9057): infoDrawable=72
09-08 22:16:33.000: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x4c0b0000
09-08 22:16:33.000: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=11: calling run()
09-08 22:16:33.007: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=11: exiting
09-08 22:16:33.008: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=11: bye!
09-08 22:16:33.008: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=0: freeing
09-08 22:16:33.009: D/ActivityThread(9057): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{417d1800 token=android.os.BinderProxy@417d1038 {com.golden.smsserver/com.golden.smsserver.MainActivity}}
09-08 22:16:33.029: D/ActivityThread(9057): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{417d1800 token=android.os.BinderProxy@417d1038 {com.golden.smsserver/com.golden.smsserver.MainActivity}}
09-08 22:16:33.117: D/libEGL(9057): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
09-08 22:16:33.126: D/libEGL(9057): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_mtk.so
09-08 22:16:33.147: D/libEGL(9057): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mtk.so
09-08 22:16:33.156: D/libEGL(9057): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
09-08 22:16:33.243: D/OpenGLRenderer(9057): Enabling debug mode 0
09-08 22:16:36.226: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x4e02e000
09-08 22:16:36.226: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=11: calling run()
09-08 22:16:36.229: I/System.out(9057): ns7iqohduryaote
09-08 22:16:36.317: I/System.out(9057): [socket][0] connection /192.168.10.9:8080;LocalPort=33406(5000)
09-08 22:16:36.317: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]connect[/192.168.10.9:8080] tm:5
09-08 22:16:36.328: D/Posix(9057): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.golden.smsserver :8080 
09-08 22:16:36.424: I/System.out(9057): [socket][/192.168.104.101:33406]
09-08 22:16:36.425: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:37.273: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=12: interp stack at 0x4e082000
09-08 22:16:37.273: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=12: calling run()
09-08 22:16:37.273: I/System.out(9057): 6bui5dlvbf445wr
09-08 22:16:37.299: I/System.out(9057): [socket][1] connection /192.168.10.9:8080;LocalPort=34375(5000)
09-08 22:16:37.300: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]connect[/192.168.10.9:8080] tm:5
09-08 22:16:37.300: D/Posix(9057): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.golden.smsserver :8080 
09-08 22:16:40.457: I/System.out(9057): [socket][/192.168.104.101:34375]
09-08 22:16:40.457: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:41.496: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:10
09-08 22:16:41.496: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:41.497: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:10
09-08 22:16:41.497: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]shutdownInput
09-08 22:16:41.497: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:41.497: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]shutdownInput
09-08 22:16:41.499: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]close[34375]
09-08 22:16:41.501: I/System.out(9057): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:34375]
09-08 22:16:41.502: I/System.out(9057): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:34375]
09-08 22:16:41.513: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=13: interp stack at 0x4e223000
09-08 22:16:41.513: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=13: calling run()
09-08 22:16:41.514: I/System.out(9057): urz5mb57hes3124
09-08 22:16:41.549: I/System.out(9057): [socket][2] connection /192.168.10.9:8080;LocalPort=36147(5000)
09-08 22:16:41.549: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]connect[/192.168.10.9:8080] tm:5
09-08 22:16:41.550: D/Posix(9057): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.golden.smsserver :8080 
09-08 22:16:41.640: I/System.out(9057): [socket][/192.168.104.101:36147]
09-08 22:16:41.640: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:42.206: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:10
09-08 22:16:42.210: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in Recvfrom
09-08 22:16:42.210: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]read is 0
09-08 22:16:42.211: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:42.211: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:10
09-08 22:16:42.219: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:42.219: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]shutdownInput
09-08 22:16:42.219: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]close[36147]
09-08 22:16:42.220: I/System.out(9057): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:36147]
09-08 22:16:42.220: I/System.out(9057): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:36147]
09-08 22:16:42.229: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=14: interp stack at 0x4e22b000
09-08 22:16:42.229: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=14: calling run()
09-08 22:16:42.230: I/System.out(9057): whm0kske88z9hwr
09-08 22:16:42.233: I/System.out(9057): [socket][3] connection /192.168.10.9:8080;LocalPort=57208(5000)
09-08 22:16:42.234: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]connect[/192.168.10.9:8080] tm:5
09-08 22:16:42.235: D/Posix(9057): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.golden.smsserver :8080 
09-08 22:16:42.238: I/System.out(9057): [socket][/192.168.104.101:57208]
09-08 22:16:42.238: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:42.759: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:10
09-08 22:16:42.760: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in Recvfrom
09-08 22:16:42.760: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]read is 0
09-08 22:16:42.760: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:42.760: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:10
09-08 22:16:42.761: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:42.761: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]shutdownInput
09-08 22:16:42.761: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]close[57208]
09-08 22:16:42.762: I/System.out(9057): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:57208]
09-08 22:16:42.762: I/System.out(9057): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:57208]
09-08 22:16:42.763: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=15: interp stack at 0x4e233000
09-08 22:16:42.764: D/dalvikvm(9057): threadid=15: calling run()
09-08 22:16:42.765: I/System.out(9057): 769h9vhnoeafrbi
09-08 22:16:42.768: I/System.out(9057): [socket][4] connection /192.168.10.9:8080;LocalPort=60430(5000)
09-08 22:16:42.770: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]connect[/192.168.10.9:8080] tm:5
09-08 22:16:42.773: D/Posix(9057): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.golden.smsserver :8080 
09-08 22:16:42.775: I/System.out(9057): [socket][/192.168.104.101:60430]
09-08 22:16:42.775: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:43.335: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:10
09-08 22:16:43.340: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in Recvfrom
09-08 22:16:43.340: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]read is 0
09-08 22:16:43.341: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:43.341: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:10
09-08 22:16:43.347: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:43.347: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]shutdownInput
09-08 22:16:43.347: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]close[60430]
09-08 22:16:43.348: I/System.out(9057): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:60430]
09-08 22:16:43.348: I/System.out(9057): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:60430]
09-08 22:16:43.349: I/System.out(9057): 4fm3442av72z63k
09-08 22:16:43.355: I/System.out(9057): [socket][5] connection /192.168.10.9:8080;LocalPort=41743(5000)
09-08 22:16:43.355: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]connect[/192.168.10.9:8080] tm:5
09-08 22:16:43.356: D/Posix(9057): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.golden.smsserver :8080 
09-08 22:16:43.359: I/System.out(9057): [socket][/192.168.104.101:41743]
09-08 22:16:43.360: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:44.000: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:10
09-08 22:16:44.010: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in Recvfrom
09-08 22:16:44.010: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]read is 0
09-08 22:16:44.010: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:44.011: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:10
09-08 22:16:44.012: I/System.out(9057): rx timeout:5000
09-08 22:16:44.012: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]shutdownInput
09-08 22:16:44.012: I/System.out(9057): [CDS]close[41743]
09-08 22:16:44.013: I/System.out(9057): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:41743]
09-08 22:16:44.013: I/System.out(9057): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:41743]
09-08 22:16:44.015: I/System.out(9057): z56eof2knllxpm3
```

**Update 2**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{
    public boolean StartInfo;
    CustomAdapter ca;
    ArrayList<MyMessageDetails> titles = new ArrayList<MyMessageDetails>();
    String BaseUrl = My URL
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btnsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
        btnsend.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnsend:
            Button btnsend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend);
            EditText etcounter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcounter);
            if (StartInfo){
                btnsend.setText("Start");
                etcounter.setEnabled(true);
                StartInfo = false;
            }else{
                btnsend.setText("Stop");
                etcounter.setEnabled(true);
                StartInfo = true;
                new RequestTask().execute(BaseUrl);

            }

            break;

        }
    }

class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        // constants
        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        int timeoutConnection = 5000;

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        System.out.println(GlobalVariables.getRandomString(15));
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url[0] + "?id=" + GlobalVariables.getRandomString(15));
        try {
            HttpResponse getResponse = client.execute(httpget);
            getResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control:", "no-cache");
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                Log.w("MyApp", "Download Error: " + statusCode + "| for URL: " + url);
                return null;
            }

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getResponseEntity.getContent()));  

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
                total.append("\n");
            }

            line = total.toString();
            return line;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("MyApp", "Download Exception : " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        TextView txtstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);
        txtstatus.setText("Status: Downloading Data, Please Wait....");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
            TextView txtstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);
            txtstatus.setText("Status: Downloading Complete.");
            if(result.toString().length() > 10) {
                MyMessageDetails Detail;
                String[] mydata = result.split("\\|s\\|");
                for (String value : mydata) 
                {
                    if (value.contains("|")){
                        String[] details = value.split("\\|n\\|");
                        String mymsg = null;
                        Detail = new MyMessageDetails();
                        Detail.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        for (String mydetail : details) 
                        {

                            if (mydetail.startsWith("_From:_")){
                                mymsg = "From: " + mydetail.replace("_From:_", "")+ "\n";
    Detail.setMsgBody(mymsg);
                            }
                        }
                        titles.add(Detail);
                    }

                }
                if (titles.size() > 0){
                    ListView listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstmsgs);
                    ca = new CustomAdapter(titles , MainActivity.this);
                    listView1.setAdapter(ca);
                }else{
                    if (StartInfo){

                                         new RequestTask().execute(BaseUrl);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                if (StartInfo){

                    new RequestTask().execute(BaseUrl);
                }
            }

        } catch(NullPointerException e) {

                TextView txtstatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtstatus);
                txtstatus.setText("Status: " + "Error: " + e.getCause());
        }

    } 

}
```

Comment: post the stacktrace please

Comment: thanks, I posted some of it.

Comment: There is no `Exception` thrown?

Comment: unfortunate nothing. It seems every thing is normal. I locked screen orientation too.

Comment: so when the screen turns off it stops downloading and then when you go back in it doesn't download?

Comment: suppose screen is on every thing fine, screen is off every thing fine, after half an hour app doing nothing and seems restarted.

Comment: can you post the `Activity` from where you are calling this?

Comment: You mean whole class?

Comment: yes, post the Class that is calling the AsyncTask